# Query dataframe to create new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a set of products, indicated by their codes and I am interested in the top 5 selling products for the month (let's say their `product_id`'s are P112 (Top 1), P134 (Top 2), P219 (Top 3), P361 (Top 4), and P443 (Top 5), although these change from month to month). I have a table that has the `employee_id`, `customer_id`, `product_id`, and `purchase_date`, and each row in the table represents a sale. I am only interested in the sales that have a top 5 product, because I want to show the distribution of top 5 sales for each employee. Essentially, I want to create a new table that has a unique employee for each row, and then how many sales they have for each of the top 5 products as columns.

Given the following table (much longer in actuality) and ids for the top 5 products:

```
Employee_id | Customer_id | Product_id | Date     |
        E12 |         C10 |       P112 | 10/05/18 |
        E11 |         C5  |       P400 | 10/05/18 |
        E20 |         C19 |       P219 | 10/06/18 |
        E23 |         C10 |       P155 | 10/07/18 |
        E19 |         C06 |       P219 | 10/07/18 | ...
```

The resulting dataframe would look something like this

```
Employee_id | Top1 | Top2 | Top3 | Top4 | Top5 |
E12         |    1 |    0 |    5 |    6 |    0 |
E19         |    3 |    2 |    1 |    0 |    1 |
E23         |    2 |    1 |    0 |    4 |    2 | 
E44         |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 | ...
```

I am not sure how to go from the first dataframe to the second dataframe in a clean and clear manner. I was planning to use Pandas. One idea I had was to iterate through the first dataframe, and create a dictionary for each of the top products, where the key would be the `employee_id` and the value would be the count (which gets incremented if the top product shows up for an employee). A lot of the implementation details are missing though. I would love any guidance, code, or suggested approaches. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter only top5 product by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), then get counts by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for correct ordering of columns and last create new columns names with `f-strings` and `list comprehension`:

```
#top5 created dynamically from column Product_id
#top5 = df['Product_id'].value_counts().index[:5])

top5 = ['P112','P134','P219','P361','P443']

df = (df[df['Product_id'].isin(top5)]
         .groupby(['Employee_id','Product_id'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns=top5, fill_value=0))

df.columns = [f'Top{x}' for x in range(1,6)]
print (df)
             Top1  Top2  Top3  Top4  Top5
Employee_id                              
E12             1     0     0     0     0
E19             0     0     1     0     0
E20             0     0     1     0     0
```

---

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Employee_id  Top1  Top2  Top3  Top4  Top5
0         E12     1     0     0     0     0
1         E19     0     0     1     0     0
2         E20     0     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Can you please check which one is better either `size` or `value_counts` with this line `df[df['Product_id'].isin(top5)].groupby('Employee_id')['Product_id'].value_counts().unstack().reindex(columns=top5, fill_value=0)` curious to know the performance. Thank you.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - Hard question, it depends of data. But I try some timings `np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'A':np.random.randint(10000,size=N)})`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa and get `In [21]: %timeit (df.groupby('B')['A'].value_counts())
517 ms ± 21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [22]: %timeit (df.groupby(['B','A']).size())
488 ms ± 8.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - there is diffeence `size` is faster `40ms`, maybe because no sorting.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - For `np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'A':np.random.randint(100,size=N)})` I get `%timeit (df.groupby(['B','A']).size())
135 ms ± 517 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit (df.groupby('B')['A'].value_counts())
366 ms ± 2.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: Thank you good to know the difference. Also, check with `sort=False` in `value_counts` and update the same in the answer that would be a reference for others who think like same as me.

Comment: Not sure I am not able to tag your name, might be the font issue.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - No problem, if add comment after my answer it create red notify. I also try `%timeit (df.groupby('B')['A'].value_counts(sort=False))
364 ms ± 12.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`, but small difference

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - btw, it should be question - what is faster ;)

Comment: @jezrael thanks for this awesome response! My question is what about those who don't have any sales in the top 10? Currently that is not incorporated into your solution. In the example above, this would be employee 44. Essentially I want all 0s for those employees.

Comment: @JaneSully  - Give me a sec.

Comment: @JaneSully - So I understand it this way - if some Employee_id have no top5 Product_id values, output is 0 rows. So need change `df[df['Product_id'].isin(top5)]` to `df` - removing  filtering.

Comment: @jezrael! Awesome that seemed to work. However, I am not sure why it works. I am not sure where we specify to only use the top 10 columns (initially I understood that to be in the isin part), and ignore the rest. Do you mind quickly explaining that part? Thanks!

Comment: @JaneSully - Not very complicated. Main work do `reindex` - it filter only top5 values, so another rows with no top5 get only 0 rows. `Groupby + size` count all values.